# Tourist attractions in Idaho during Winter

Tags: tours, winter, idaho

I am wondering if there is any places to go in Idaho during Winter. I live fairly close to Idaho, and I haven't really had a chance to fully explore the area. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What kind of sights or activities are you mainly interested in? Edit in some more info in the question, and you'll get better answers :)

Comment: @Chris - can you also perhaps include whether you plan on doing it yourself, or whether you want a tour group?

Comment: @Jonic It can be any sights or activities. I know that Idaho is usually covered by snow during Winter, so I would assume there are very limited places to go and things to do.

Comment: @Mark Mayo I would like to go as a group of 3-4 people.

Comment: @ChrisJang - but are you self-organising, or do you want a tour company to take you around?

Comment: Closing until OP adds detail about tour group or not for travel, as it makes quite a difference to the construction of an itinerary.  @ChrisJang - please edit this into your question if you return, and flag for reopening. Thanks!